# SQL Server does not recognize table even after being refreshed

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `SlotInPlantTransaction`

As we can see clearly in this picture that the table really does, exist and I even have inserted values into the table using a Stored Procedure

[image]

However, if I try to select the table or want to update a column inside the table, somehow SQL Server said that the table does not exist
[image]

I made sure that the server and the database it connected to is the right one, along with refreshing the IntelliSense too, but it does not have any effect.

I could do fine with calling the table from right-clicking in the Object Explorer, but this way I can't make my update Stored Procedure work.

Anyone ever had similar issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the context of that database? Either check it in the upper left corner or execute `USE DatabaseName`

Comment: try dbo.SlotInPlanttransaction

Comment: Try right-click on the Table name, choose `Select top 1000 rows`, that should open a connected window with the proper query. Also, `SELECT DB_NAME()` will show you what database you are connected to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you're querying the wrong database.

As you stated, when you right click the table in the object explorer, it's working. This would be because `SSMS` will run the `USE` function on your behalf to query the right database/table.

A fast and easy way to fix that error would be calling the [`USE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
USE [DatabaseName] --Make sure to insert the DB name, not the table name.
SELECT * FROM SlotInPlantTransaction
```

Another way would be by choosing the right database from the top left `AvailableDatabases` drop down list, as shown in this picture:

[image: SSMS]

You change the `master` to your `DatabaseName` that you pick from the list.